# When a prime ideal is maximal differential ideal in a UFD?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, ideals

Is the prime ideal $\langle X^{2}+Y^{2}-1\rangle$ a maximal differential ideal in differential ring $\mathbb{Q}[X,Y]$ with
derivatives $D(X)=Y, D(Y)= -X$?

I know there are maximal ideals like $\langle X,Y-1\rangle$, $\langle X-1,Y\rangle$ containing $\langle X^{2}+Y^{2}-1\rangle$ but these are not proper differential ideals. If there exists a proper differential ideal containing $\langle X^{2}+Y^{2}-1\rangle$ then it must be generated by at least two polynomials say $f,g$. If any one the generator is of degree 1 or 2 then it is easy to see the ideal is not proper, but how to see for higher degrees of $f$ and $g$.

Comment: Also posted on MO: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/236752/when-a-prime-ideal-is-maximal-differential-ideal-in-a-ufd Maybe have a look [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5085/moderator-supported-official-guidelines-for-legitimate-crossposting/5088#5088) and at other discussions about [meta-tag:cross-posting].